# Effect of DLL to execution speed

Tags: c++, dll

First of all, I use user-defined header and corresponding `cpp` file. Then I include and so on. If I would switch to DLL, would the execution speed of the code be retarded?

Secondly, I know that in "DLL", "D" represents "dynamic" however, my friend said that there are two ways to use them: Statically and dynamically. If it is dynamic already, what we have to do with "static"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless the function is very small (so it gets inlined otherwise), using a DLL has no difference whatsoever on the performance (aside from the fact that loading a DLL does increase the startup time of your application.) Large, performance-critical applications use DLLs (for instance the Intel Math library.) There are minor penalties if the compiler cannot do whole-program optimization, but these are very small differences which usually don't matter.

Regarding static/dynamic: I assume he means that you can link against a DLL the normal way (by using an import library), which forces it to be always loaded or load it dynamically at run-time (using `LoadLibrary` and `dlopen`.) No performance difference there, but using `LoadLibrary` allows you to delay loading the library until actually needed.

Comment: Some toolchains also provide an automatic form of delay-loading, e.g. Microsoft's [`/DELAYLOAD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) switch

Comment: At a website (http://logix4u.net/vc/19-a-tutorial-on-creating-dlls-with-vc) I read that DLL is slower than conventional way. It is only a few sentences. Could you comment on that too, please?

Comment: Calling a DLL has at most the cost of calling a function through a function pointer. That's next to zero overhead for any non-trivial function (and very small functions can be just made inline.) It's comparable in cost with a virtual function call.

Answer (score 2):

1. Productivity shouldn't regress, as far as calling function from dll in general similar to local function call.
2. Two types of libs exists:

   - from one poin of view, *dynamic* libs and *static* libs. Here *static* means, that all code from the lib will be linked *statically* to your `exe`, oppositely *dynamic* lib allows to separate code from executable to *shared* library, that code will be loaded *dynamically*.
   - Then, *dynamic* libary can be linked to statically, and that means, that OS will link library to your program on startup and *dynamically*, that means, you obtain pointers to symbols, storied in library, by hands. While dynamic loading gives more flexibility, it more difficult way that using static linking.